# How to remove / replace ANSI color codes from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ansi-escape

I have trouble finding the problem with the function below. The first parameters is a string containing ANSI
color codes and the second parameter is a boolean.

If the boolean is set to `false`, a full remove is made on the string.

If the boolean is set to `true`, a loop convert every color codes into something easier for me to parse later.

I suspect the `RegExp` being the problem as it is confused between 1;33 and 0;31 for some reason.

```
var colorReplace = function( input, replace ) {
        var replaceColors = {
            "0;31" : "{r",
            "1;31" : "{R",

            "0;32" : "{g",
            "1;32" : "{G",

            "0;33" : "{y",
            "1;33" : "{Y",

            "0;34" : "{b",
            "1;34" : "{B",

            "0;35" : "{m",
            "1;35" : "{M",

            "0;36" : "{c",
            "1;36" : "{C",

            "0;37" : "{w",
            "1;37" : "{W",

            "1;30" : "{*",

            "0" : "{x"
        };

        if ( replace )
        {
            for( k in replaceColors )
            {
                //console.log( "\033\[" + k + "m" + replaceColors[ k ] );
                var re = new RegExp( "\033\[[" + k + "]*m", "g" );

                input = input.replace( re, replaceColors[ k ] );
            }
        } else {
            input = input.replace( /\033\[[0-9;]*m/g, "" );
        }

        return input;
    };

console.log( "abcd\033[1;32mefgh\033[1;33mijkl\033[0m" );
console.log( colorReplace( "abcd\033[1;32mefgh\033[1;33mijkl", true ) );
```

The actual output is:

[image]

Where it should be `abcd{Gefgh{Yijkl`

Anyone know what's wrong now?

Comment: The second parameter of the replaceColor is a boolean and it will either replace all the color codes with an easy-to-read (IMO) and easy-to-parse string or if false is used, it will remove all colorcodes found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Regex was wrong. It should be `"\\033\\[" + k + "m"`, not `"\033\[[" + k + "]*m"`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use octal codes in both strings and RegExps

```
x = "\033[1mHello Bold World!\033[0m\n";
x = x.replace(/[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g,"");
print(x);
```

This matches most [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), including extended VT100 codes, archaic/proprietary printer codes, and so on.

Comment: This works! What would be the solution using a RegExp object ? I am thinking about either removing ( your solution ) or replacing with an equivalent/easier to remember and parse string.

Comment: @Cybrix: `/\033\[[0-9;]*m/` equals `RegExp("\033\[[0-9;]*m")`.

Comment: @Àlvaro, Thank you. Then, if I want to use a variable inside the RegExp parameter this should work: `var byellow = "1;33"; var re = new RegExp( "\033\[" + byellow + "*m", "g" ); string = string.replace( re, "{Y}" );` ?